# Wordpress animated shape divider

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have been using a animated shape divider with some custom css, it is making a wave animate from left to right, but when i toggle to a tablet or mobile it is strangely glitching oustide the main website.

I have been searching for a code solution to turn it off but regardly with no succes.
I am looking for a code for when someone is going to visite my website on a tablet or mobile, it removes/blocks the animated waves.

The CSS i am currently using

```
body {
     overflow-x:hidden;
} 
.elementor-shape-bottom {
     bottom: -1px;
     animation: wave 22s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
     width: 210%;
 } 
@keyframes wave {
   0% {
     margin-left: 0;
   }
     50% {
     margin-left: -1600px;
   }
   100% {
     margin-left: 0px;
   }
 }


body {
     overflow-x:hidden;
} 
.elementor-shape-top {
     bottom: -1px;
     animation: wave 22s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
     width: 210%;
 } 
@keyframes wave {
   0% {
     margin-left: 0;
   }
     50% {
     margin-left: -1600px;
   }
   100% {
     margin-left: 0px;
   }
 }


body {
     overflow-x:hidden;
} 
.elementor-shape {
     bottom: -1px;
     animation: wave 22s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
     width: 210%;
 } 
@keyframes wave {
   0% {
     margin-left: 0;
   }
     50% {
     margin-left: -1600px;
   }
   100% {
     margin-left: 0px;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Could you possibly include some HTML snippet, so we can see what goes where?

Answer (score 0):

Elementor add this `data-elementor-device-mode` attribute on the body tag to identify the device. that's why two different lines are required. The first-line CSS will apply when you are on a tablet device and the second line will apply when you are on a mobile device.

Add this CSS in your code.

```css
//This will stop animation on tablet device
body.elementor-default[data-elementor-device-mode="tablet"] .elementor-shape {
  animation: unset;
}

//This will stop animation on mobile device
body.elementor-default[data-elementor-device-mode="mobile"] .elementor-shape {
  animation: unset;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your response.
Generally, we appreciate if you can add some more explanation on why your code works and how, e.g. why two different lines are required. That enables others to learn from your knowledge instead of just copying the solution. Anyway, nice first contribution.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Elementor add this `data-elementor-device-mode` attribute on the body tag to identify the device. that's why two different lines are required. The first-line CSS will apply when you are on a tablet device and the second line will apply when you are on a mobile device.